# counter in lambda expression streamwriter

Tags: linq, streamwriter

I have the follow expression:

```
myGrid.ForEach(Sub(Model) myStreamWriter.WriteLine(Function(x As Integer) (x + 1)))
```

Of course it's not working. I want to write in a text file (WriteLine) a sequential number (1, 2, 3, etc.) for each record collected in the variable varGrid type: List (of mytable)

Any idea? It's fine CSharp code too.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could declare the counter outside of the foreach lambda, just as you would declare it outside of the scope of a foreach loop.

```
var x = 1;
myGrid.ForEach(model => myStreamWriter.WriteLine(x++.ToString()));
```

Comment: The same with VB.NET: myGrid.ForEach(Sub(Model) myStreamWriter.WriteLine(System.Math.Max(System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(x), x - 1))).    It worked!!! TKS!